# setting SSH access to localhost

Tags: ssh, key, localhost

I am trying to setup ssh access to my own local machine.

I have created the id_rsa key using ssh-keygen. 
I added id_rsa.pub to authroized_keys in .ssh/
I made sure the permission of authorized_keys is 640
I enabled public-key authentication in sshd_config & restarted ssh

> RSAAuthentication yes
>
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
>
> AuthorizedKeysFile  %u/.ssh/authorized_keys

However I am unable to login to ssh.

The error I recieved is as follows

```
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/rahul/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug2: key: /home/rahul/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fa12de58e70),
debug2: key: /home/rahul/.ssh/gitHubKey ((nil)), explicit
debug2: key: /home/rahul/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer (0x7fa12de59060), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rahul/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rahul/.ssh/gitHubKey
no such identity: /home/rahul/.ssh/gitHubKey: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rahul/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen auth.log (or system.log, secure.log, ect where opensshd write its logs) possibly the problem is that .ssh/authorized_keys must have 600 not 640.

Example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Hope it helps.

#### Edit:

We will uninstall openssh-server and purge configuration files:

```
(root)# apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
```

Now we will install again with default settings:

```
(root)# apt-get install openssh-server
```

Now we will generate our private/public key:

```
(rahul)$ ssh-keygen
```

Now we will copy the key in our local user, you will need to write your password.

```
(rahul)$ ssh-copy-id rahul@localhost
```

Try to connect now with:

```
(rahul)$ ssh rahul@localhost
```

Now it may work.

Comment: I tried your suggesstion & no luck. The auth.log has the following error. ` PWD=/home/rahul ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
Feb 25 13:26:07 rahul-ThinkPad-X240 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by rahul(uid=0)
Feb 25 13:26:37 rahul-ThinkPad-X240 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 25 13:26:42 rahul-ThinkPad-X240 sshd[11371]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]`

Comment: Are you trying to connect to user "root"? In this case you need to add your public key in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, not /home/rahul/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I am not actually... I am doing 'ssh rahul@localhost' .. I have no idea why it is showing root user in the log file.

Comment: What linux distribution are you using? I'll update my answer with steps to reinstall openssh-server with default settings and generate a new private/public key and copy it with apropiate commands in debian/ubuntu.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 & I followed all the steps to letter in the link you mentioned & its still not working...

Comment: Try these steps, uninstalling and purging configuration files and later recreating private/public keys and copying it with ssh-copy-id command.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to `ssh localhost` without a password, these 5 lines should cover all the bases. Tested on Ubuntu.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
ssh-keygen -q -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -N '' -t ed25519
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo "* $(cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub)" >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod go-w ~ ~/.ssh; chmod ugo-x,go-w ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Explanations, line-by-line:

1. Create `.ssh` directory if it does not yet exist
2. Create a new private/public key pair if it does not yet exist
3. Add the new public key to our `authorized_keys` file, i.e. allow ourselves to log in without a password
4. Add the computer's public host key to our `known_hosts`; this is the list of computers we recognize and trust
5. Restrict permissions on sensitive ssh files in the way `ssh` mandates